# Slot machine drawing lines for result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code:

```
<div id="machine">
    <div id="0"></div>
    <div id="1"></div>
    <div id="2"></div>
    <div id="3"></div>
    <div id="4"></div>
</div>
<div id="play">
    <button>Play</button>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/71a41pcz/3)

My question is how do I draw lines like the below for the result?

[image]

Also I would like to know if this is a good approach for making slot machine. If not how and with what then?

Comment: Can you show us what you attempted to do for those lines and what didn't work as expected?

Comment: I have full code for slot machine .I can give you , contact me here codeking4u@gmail.com

Comment: @Frederik.L erm I'm getting the result from an API and spin it accordingly to the correct px. for example for 7 to be at the center it should be -5640px. but i  have not yet draw the line because i do not know how

Comment: @LimSY What I was saying is, it would help you get better answers if you show an attempt to draw lines like below ones with an actual problem doing so. Otherwise there is no real problem and no definitively good answers, hence not much time will be invested to redact them.

Answer (score 0):

If you had only to code those spinning things, 5 divs would have been just fine, but if you want to draw those lines, I suggest you use a canvas to draw all the slot, or place a transparent canvas over your divs to draw the lines only.

Canvas reference: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp